# JupyterHub - Set separate home directory for each user in the JupyterHub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I installed Anaconda environment on CentOS 7 operating system. With `conda` command I installed JupyterHub and all the necessary tools. I started the JupyterHub, after configuring it. I used `jupyterhub -f /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_conf.py &` instruction. I created users on the host system and gave them a home directory to be under the JupyterHub. In the JupyterHub config file I put: `c.Spawner.notebook_dir=/home/conda/multiusers`. And then, in that folder, I created the home directories for all the users.

How can I instruct JupyterHub to load each user into its home folder and not into common "multiusers" folder?

Thank you in advance!